# Display character differently in Vim via Vimrc

Tags: vim

Currently in my `vimrc` I have the following line:

```
au BufWinEnter * call matchadd('SpecialKey', '[       　 ⁠     ]')
```

Between the brackets are various [Unicode space characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28punctuation%29#Spaces_in_Unicode). This highlights Unicode spaces so that I can tell them apart from normal ones (I have a few documents that I use em-spaces in quite heavily).

However, I was wondering if there is some way to display a character as another character in Vim? This way I could display wide spaces as two normal space characters, for instance, but when writing out the file the appropriate Unicode space character would be written. I know this is possible for tabs and whitespace errors with `list` and `listchars`, but I'd like a way to display any character as any other character (or string).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the *conceal* feature.

See `:help conceal`.

Comment: Note that this is single-character replacement only (not the two regular spaces the question mentions), and conceal has the potential to interfere with the regular syntax highlighting, unfortunately.

Comment: Yah, thanks for the answer, but I was unable to do what I was looking for with this feature (still though, it's a good one to know about).